# Build a solution to process large data set of Unprocessed agreement to Processed

Tags: cloud, salesforce

I am new to the concept of Cloud Computing in general and salesforce.com specifically and have a bit of Java experience. I have one task to be done and need commuinty's help in that. Below is the descritption of what is require of me and my questions related to that

1 : Have to create a functionality  to run on schedule that processes the information (Custom Object)

2 : Schedule the functionality in Salesforce

3 : Upload a CSV file example to Unprocessed agreement custom object

My questions (Here i am anticipating some direct few lines answer and/or links to the related user guides or tutorials):

For 1: How to create a functionality and to make it run on schedule ?

For 2: What does this statement means ??

For 3: What is the significance of Comma Seperated Values, why and how it can be uploaded.

Once again, i am not looking for direct whole solution to this problem but some pointers/ hint to get me started and point me in the right direction  with the saleforce.com

Looking forward to hear from you

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On reading your requirement i would think you would need to process records from a object periodically and schedule it run at particular time periods.

Salesforce has something called a batch process which would process records in batches of 200 and you can schedule this batch process to run at specific times.
Take a look at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm to know abt batch process

You can schedule this batch process by writing a class implementing schedulable interface.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

For 3, i am assuming you want to import data into SF. You can use Data loader which is a application you can download here http://sourceforge.net/projects/sforce-app-dl/

and more info regarding data loader here http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader